# Выдернуть значение тега выше на одно дом дерево элемента. JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При нажатие на картинку выполняется этот код `modalImg.src = this.src;` Все работает и отображает нужный ресурс. Мне надо что я выдернул значение тега блока в котором лежит эта картинка. Вот как оно лежит в консоле.

```
<div name="3" id="carouselRow30" class="carousel-item active">
 <img name="imgPost" class="w-100 myImgClass col-md-4"src="/Content/Files/15.08.2018/20055/114176096_d1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
```

Мне нужно записать в переменную значение тега Name где в данном случаи лежит "3". При  нажатие код реагирует и записывает правильную картинку, значит можно как-то вытащит элемент выше этой картинки. Как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var someVar = $(element).parent().attr('name')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
someImg.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("name"))
});
```

```html
<div name="3" id="carouselRow30" class="carousel-item active">
 <img name="imgPost" class="w-100 myImgClass col-md-4"src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OCO3qYvqQ8w/hqdefault.jpg" id="someImg" alt="">
 </div>
```